# Why does socket close when sending message over socket?

Tags: python, sockets

Why does my connection stop after 3 print statements if I have the `conn.send()` line? If that line is commented out, the connection stays open indefinitely. It is hitting the exception for some reason, but I don't know why and I am inexperienced with python.

server.py:

```
import random
import signal
import socket
import struct
import sys
import time

PORT = 1234
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('', PORT))
s.listen(1)
print("Server started on port %u" % PORT)

try:
    while True:
        (conn, addr) = s.accept()
        conn.setblocking(0)
        print("Client connected: %s:%d" % addr)
        while True:
            print "hey"
            conn.send("random")
            time.sleep(1)
except:
    s.close()
    print "exception"
```

client.py:

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 1234                 # Reserve a port for your service.

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

Comment: The last line in `client.py` is missing parentheses.  Whether or not they exist in the code you are actually running could affect the result.

Comment: @ErlVolton unfortunately that didn't change anything.

Comment: Does it still print `"hey"` 3 times?

Comment: I might suggest that you use `sendall()`, it's not the answer to your question someone did touch on the topic in their answer.

Comment: @ErlVolton already tried sandal(). same behavior.

Comment: Yes, see my answer for why you are seeing this behavior (which `sendall()` definitely won't change).  It's just something I wanted to point out as a common stumbling block for people new to python.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is the socket is actually closed after the clients first `recv()`, your server just doesn't realize it until the third attempt at `send()`.  Calling `close()` in your client didn't change anything because previously the program was terminating which closed the socket anyway.   [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899593/python-doesnt-detect-a-closed-socket-until-the-second-send) explains why this is very likely what's happening.  To test this theory, you could try having the client sleep (or `select`) and print more `recv()` calls, before closing the socket.